# Can I boot from a saved state such that all the programs and windows are positioned the same and are running as they were when I saved the state?

Tags: windows-10, boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Can I boot from a saved state such that all the programs and windows are positioned the same and are running as they were when I saved the state?

Essentially, I am trying to set up my flight simulator environment in a way that I do not have to open and configure all the different programs I use every time I boot up the computer.

For example, if I have the flight simulator open, Notepad open, Chrome open, instrument software, and I save this state, I want to boot into that exact same state as if it was a virtual machine. I would use VirtualBox but it is my understanding that the GPU can't actually be utilized in the virtual environment.

There seem to be so many options so I was wondering if anyone would be able to point me in the direction of some of the better options or maybe even the "best fit". Thanks!

FWIW, I don't think I can just "sleep" or "hibernate" as I often have my PC and completely disconnected from a power source but I could be very wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate is your only option and *eventually* you will need a fresh reboot and lose the stuff.

Hibernation is a literal save of the memory to disk followed by a full system shutdown.  It also has an extra step of saving device state.

Unlike sleep, it doesn't require power.  It is truly a shutdown.

When the computer is booted next, windows checks that the hardware hasn't changed, sees that there is a hibernation file and that it hasn't been touched.

If these things are still OK (as in the same as before the hibernation),
It loads the hibernation file back into memory and restores the devices and driver states before allowing the machine to run again.

Comment: This also requires that there there has not been any changes to the hardware in use. The save of memory also has a extra step of saving device state, it then restores the devices and driver states before allowing the machine to run again.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @NiKiZe .  I updated my answer.

Comment: Also note some programs do not work well with hibernate, but it is rare.  This is more often true with programs that access the real world time for functions.  If there is a massive time jump, I have seen issues happen.

Comment: Does this "hardware change" apply to usb-devices as well (if I change the port a device is plugged into, will that cause an issue?) @SeñorCMasMas

Comment: I just tried this myself and from my unscientific sample of exactly ONE, .. no, it still loaded the hibernation image after moving my mouse to a new USB port.

Comment: Usb is always "disconnected" before hibernation, and then re-detected after startup.

Comment: Thanks all! The hibernation seems a bit unstable so I'm going to do some testing with it to try to make it more reliable.